# JavaFX how to rotate drawing round center of it

Tags: java, canvas, javafx

I've got a problem with the rotate method. I want to rotate a drawing around the center of it, but I don't want to rotate the Canvas object, just the drawing inside it. 
**artHorizon is canvas Object(400,400)**
Or maybe it would be better to move coordinate system to the center of convas object?

Here is a drawing method:

```
public void drawHorizon(GraphicsContext gc, double degrees, double translate) {

        gc.translate(0, translate);

        gc.rotate(degrees);

        gc.setFill(Color.rgb(0, 61, 144));
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, artHorizon.getWidth() * 2, 150);
        gc.setFill(Color.rgb(59, 41, 39));
        gc.fillRect(0, 150, 400, 150);

    }
```

And initialize:

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        GraphicsContext gc = artHorizon.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.rotate(20);//here I want to rotate gc around center
        drawHorizon(gc, 0, 0);


    }
```

Comment: You want to rotate it dynamically or only when you initialize your program ?

Comment: Dynamically during the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rotate around a point

Replace existing transform with new one and then rotate. setTransform the last two values are the canvas pixel coordinates of the new origin where x = 0 and y = 0.

```
gc.setTransform(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, artHorizon.getWidth() / 2.0, 150.0);
gc.rotate(degrees);
```

The origin is now at `artHorizon.getWidth() / 2`, `150.0` so you have to draw from that point. You will need the diagonal width so you fill the whole canvas.

```
double len = Math.sqrt(
       artHorizon.getWidth() * artHorizon.getWidth() + 
       artHorizon.getHeight() * artHorizon.getHeight()) / 2.0;
```

Then you render the horizon offset from the origin

```
gc.fillRect(-len, -150, len * 2, 150); // top half
// change colour
gc.fillRect(-len, 0, len * 2, 400); // bottom half
```

You can return the canvas back to default with

```
gc.setTransform(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

Comment: It helped a lot ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `Rotate` with the appropriate pivot specified to `Affine`'s constructor. The result can be passed to the `transform` method of the `GraphicsContext`. Furthermore to ensure the `Canvas` is filed to it's edges, add some offset. The maximum of the dimensions of the `Canvas` will surely suffice:

```
gc.transform(new Affine(new Rotate(20, artHorizon.getWidth()/2, artHorizon.getHeight()/2)));
// gc.rotate(20);
```

```
public void drawHorizon(GraphicsContext gc, double degrees, double translate) {
    gc.translate(0, translate);

    gc.rotate(degrees);
    double maxDimension = Math.max(artHorizon.getWidth(), artHorizon.getHeight());

    gc.setFill(Color.rgb(0, 61, 144));
    gc.fillRect(-maxDimension, 0, maxDimension * 3, 150);
    gc.setFill(Color.rgb(59, 41, 39));
    gc.fillRect(-maxDimension, 150, maxDimension * 3, 150);
}
```